# jquery accordion slow to load

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-accordion

Lots of questions on jquery accordion. Mine is specific to this site:

http://sabadesignstudio.com/saba/newSMP/index.php

You will probably see that it takes a while to load and while loading, the CSS hasn't quite loaded either.

I just changed hosts to Blue Host today thinking it might be faster on their servers.

Any clues as to how I can make this load normally would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You should link jquery/jquery UI libraries via [Google](https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/devguide) or [Microsoft](http://www.asp.net/ajaxlibrary/cdn.ashx) CDNs.

Also, try running [YSlow](http://yslow.org/) or [PageSpeed](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/) against your site and evaluate the changes those tools suggest.

Here is the PageSpeed output:

**High priority (3)**

```
Serve scaled images
Leverage browser caching
Optimize images
```

**Medium priority (1)**

```
Combine images into CSS sprites
```

**Low priority (10)**

```
Defer parsing of JavaScript
Inline Small CSS
Optimize the order of styles and scripts
Minify CSS
Specify a cache validator
Minify JavaScript
Minify HTML
Specify image dimensions
Specify a character set
Remove query strings from static resources
```